# Performence issue while using curl in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, curl, hive

I am trying to fetch one column from Hive and based on the value of that column, I need to execute `curl` command.

This is how I am generating my Column list

```
val list = hiveContext.sql("select application_number from t").collect()

for(l1 <- list) {
    val z = a.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
    val cmd = Seq("curl", "-X", "POST", "--insecure", "--header",
                  "Content-Type: application/json", "--header", 
                  "Accept: application/json", "-d", 
                  "{\"searchText\":\"+'z'+\",\"qf\":\"applId\"}", "https://link")
    val r = cmd.!!
}
```

Now, I have stored the data in `r` variable in a perfect manner.

But my list has 10 million records. So it takes lot of time while iterating over it.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: How are you able to accommodate a list on the driver with that size?

Comment: Why don't you use an actual HTTP Connection class provided in the JVM? Also for loops in Spark over collected objects are rarely a good thing. There is no clear advantage of using Spark here

Answer (score 1):

You could have Spark use either `.map` or an UDF to iterate over each record and do the curl request from the worker nodes.
The upside is that you would never have to collect all records on the master and then run 10M curl requests. T
he downside is that all curl requests are async, so order is not guaranteed and if your cluster is big enough you can actually bring down the receiving end of the curl requests.
The other downside is that this comes with major side-effects.
If the Spark Job fails halfway through 5M requests have already been posted.

Besides using curl requests fired from the system I would also use native JVM HTTP
`import scalaj.http.Http`

Something like this

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import scala.util.Try
import scalaj.http.Http


val spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .master("local[2]")
  .appName("test")
  .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

// val list = (0 to 100).toDF("application_number").as[Int]
val list = hiveContext.sql("select application_number from t").as[Int]

val r = list.map(application_number => {
  Try(Http("https://link").postData(s"""{"searchText": "$application_number","qf":"applId"}""")
    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
    .asString.body).toOption
}).collect()

println(r.toList)
```

scalaj-http is blocking, but thread safe, so for even greater performance (& risk) you could wrap it in an execution framework (Futures) with a timeout or so